# Добавить букву Ё в шаблон регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть такой шаблон проверки:

```
([0-9A-Za-z]{2,16})|([0-9\u0410-\u044f]{2,16})
```

Помогите добавить букву ё в unicode

Comment: А в чём проблема-то? Что мешает добавить?

Comment: Ну просто добавьте в квадратные скобки буквы `Ёё` -> `[0-9\u0410-\u044fЁё]`

Comment: Буква Ё действительно не находится в базовом кириллическом диапазоне https://unicode-table.com/en/#0401

Comment: @Let'ssayPie думаю, в таком случае ТС написал бы `а-яА-Я`

Comment: Попробовал сделал так:   [0-9\u0410-\u044f\u0451], но не может быть первой буквой

Comment: @cppquestions, да, я полностью согласен, но если хочет в другом виде, то пусть сделает так `[0-9\u0401\u0451\u0410-\u044f]`

Comment: @kapitoshka85, объясните, что вы проверяете вашим регулярным выражением? Я думаю можно найти другое, более оптимальное решение.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie Спасибо, такой вариант подошел

Comment: добавляется а-яА-ЯёЁ и прекрасно работает

Comment: @Ljil принципиально в unicode нужно было

Comment: В Интернете полно таких сервисов, см., например, https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%D1%91%D0%81#title. Щёлкните описание символа слева, всё, что нужно, будет справа.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно будет так:

```
([0-9A-Za-z]{2,16})|([0-9А-ЯЁа-яё]{2,16})
```